# AWS EMR job using PowerShell Cmdlet

Tags: powershell, amazon-web-services, emr, amazon-emr

I have a pig script that accept some arguments. I need to use AWS PowerShell Cmdlet only.
I am able to create cluster with pig installed using below command:

```
$app = New-Object  Amazon.ElasticMapReduce.Model.Application
$app.Name="Pig"
$jobid = Start-EMRJobFlow -Name "Pig Job"  -Application $app -Instances_MasterInstanceType "m3.xlarge" -Instances_KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps $true -Instances_InstanceCount 1 -LogUri "s3://mybucket/logs" -VisibleToAllUsers $true -ReleaseLabel "emr-5.7.0" -SecurityConfiguration "my-sec-grp" -JobFlowRole "EMR_EC2_DefaultRole" -ServiceRole "EMR_DefaultRole"
```

But I am not able to add step for pig job.
I followed some articles but those are very old or those are using some custom jar to submit the job. I just need to submit a pig script which is accepting some parameters.
Any help will be highly appreciated
**Note**: i need powershell specific commands. I am able to do this using AWS cli.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the way to submit pig scripts from powershell. I was following this [link](https://aws.amazon.com/articles/3681655242374956). But the problem was that its regarding Hive scripts. So the step where its creating step as

```
$runhivescriptargs = @("s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive/hive-script", `
         "--base-path", "s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/hive", `
         "--hive-versions","latest", `
         "--run-hive-script", `
         "--args", `
         "-f", "s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs/join-clicks-to-impressions.q", `
         "-d", "SAMPLE=s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads",`
         "-d", "DAY=2009-04-13", `
         "-d", "HOUR=08", `
         "-d", "NEXT_DAY=2009-04-13", `
         "-d", "NEXT_HOUR=09",`
         "-d", "INPUT=s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/tables", `
         "-d", "OUTPUT=s3://my-output-bucket/joinclick1", `
         "-d", "LIB=s3://elasticmapreduce/samples/hive-ads/libs")
```

So i followed the same steps but somehow in case of pig scripts arguments need to be passed using -p option not using -d option
So the my step creation is like:

```
$runpigscriptargs = @("s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/pig/pig-script", `
         "--base-path", "s3://us-east-1.elasticmapreduce/libs/pig", `
         "--run-pig-script", `
         "--args", `
         "-f", $scriptfile, `
         "-p", "Id=$Id",`
         "-p", "jarPath=$jarPath",`
         "-p", "inputPath=$newInputPath", `
         "-p", "outputPath=$outputPath")
```

I am not specifying pig version as i have already created a EMR cluster having latest version of pig installed
Thanks